# jquery validation plugin error placement at the last <td> in form with dynamic rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where users can add or remove rows of items. Once form is submitted, there are couple of values that I validate like values should be greater than 0 or check for if the field is filled or not and it's working now. What I want right now is that I want to show the error message for that particular line item in the last td for that tr. As users can have multiple rows, errors for that particular row should be in that rows last td. Can someone please help me how can I achieve that?

My current error placement code for input fields and select fields is this:

```
$("#ItemsForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.next());
    console.log(error);
},
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
           $(element).addClass(errorClass).parent().children("select").addClass(errorClass);
}
});
```

HTML code for one of the scenario where I have two items selected is:

```
<table class="width100" id="tableDiv">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="alignCenter">Item</th>
        <th class="alignCenter">Price</th>
        <th class="alignCenter">Quantity</th>
        <th class="alignCenter">Discount</th>
        <th class="alignCenter">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row_1">
        <td class="products alignCenter">
            <select name="item_1" id="item_1" class="products box-style select-style">
                <option value="">-- select --</option>          
                    <option value="1001" >Item 1</option>
                    <option value="1002" >Item 2</option>
                    <option value="1003" >Item 3</option>
                    <option value="1004" >Item 4</option>           
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Price_1" id="Price_1" value="999.00" class="text-box-style width95 alignCenter" disabled="disabled" /></td>
        <td class="quantity"><input type="text" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1" value="1" maxlength="4" class="quantity text-box-style width95 alignCenter"  /></td>
        <td class="discount"><input type="text" name="discount_1" id="discount_1" value="10" maxlength="3" class="discount text-box-style width95 alignCenter discountBox" /></td>
        <td class="alignCenter"><i onclick="addRow(this.form);" title="Add line item" class="fa fa-plus icon-cog" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row_2">
        <td class="products alignCenter">
            <select name="item_2" id="item_2" class="products box-style select-style">
                <option value="">-- select --</option>          
                    <option value="1001" >Item 1</option>
                    <option value="1002" >Item 2</option>
                    <option value="1003" >Item 3</option>
                    <option value="1004" >Item 4</option>           
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Price_2" id="Price_2" value="3000.00" class="text-box-style width95 alignCenter" disabled="disabled" /></td>
        <td class="quantity"><input type="text" name="quantity_2" id="quantity_2" value="2" maxlength="4" class="quantity text-box-style width95 alignCenter" /></td>
        <td class="discount"><input type="text" name="discount_2" id="discount_2" value="10" maxlength="3" class="discount text-box-style width95 alignCenter discountBox" /></td>
        <td class="alignCenter"><i onclick="removeRow('2');" title="Remove line item" class="fa fa-minus icon-cog" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="alignCenter"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="width75 box-style btn-style" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Firstly, where is the rest of the code?  Since placement within HTML markup is what you're asking about, you'd think you'd show us your actual HTML markup.  Secondly, when using `highlight`, you should also use `unhighlight` or the CSS will not be correct when the error message goes away.

Comment: @Sparky, I have edited my post to include HTML code.

Comment: You don't have any `form` tags.  Since you also don't have any meaningful validation rules, I cannot even reproduce any validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `form` tags, emptied the `value` attributes, and added a class of `required` to relevant `input` elements just so I could generate validation messages for my demo.

```
error.appendTo(element.next());
```

You were targeting `.next()` element after the `element` being validated.  However, there are no siblings after the `input` element so there is nothing there to append to.

> I want to show the error message for that particular line item in the last `td` for that `tr`

Instead you need to traverse up two levels to the parent `tr`, select all children `td`, and finally the last `td` in the set.

```
error.appendTo(element.parents('tr').children('td').last());
```

**DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/7ft5u9yj/](http://jsfiddle.net/7ft5u9yj/)**

You also need to have a `unhighlight` function to complement your `highlight` function.  Otherwise, the classes will not be correct when the error is cleared out.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).parent().children("select").addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).parent().children("select").removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted; you rock! Thanks a lot.